# How to make a file into dictionary

Tags: file, dictionary, python-3.6

There are two different files that is opened in the code.
1. 'file.txt' file looks like this:

```
33,80,71,180
280,80,260,45,240,80
200,100,119,41,150,136,181,41,100,100
75,50,87,28,75,6,50,6,37,28,49,50
```

The 'colours.txt' file looks like this:

```
2:red
3:orange
5:yellow
6:green
```

My current code below:

```
def create_colours_dictionary(filename):
    colour_dict = {}
    file = open('colours.txt', "r")
    for line in file:
            (key, value) = line.split(":")
            colour_dict[int(key.strip())] = value.strip()
    file.close()
    return colour_dict

def read_coordinates(filename, shapes_dict):
    file = open('file.txt', 'r')
    file_dict = {}
    for line in file:
            (value) = line.split()
            file_dict[line] = [value]

    print('')

def main():
    colours_dict = create_colours_dictionary('colours.txt')
    print(colours_dict)

    shapes_dict = {}
    for key in colours_dict.keys():
        shapes_dict[key] = []   
    for filename in filenames_list:
        read_coordinates(filename, shapes_dict)
    print(shapes_dict)

main()
```

What i expected to have for the out put is:

```
{2: 'red', 3: 'orange', 5: 'yellow', 6: 'green'}

{2: [['33', '80', '71', '180']], 3: [['280', '80', '260', '45', '240', '80']],
5: [['200', '100', '119', '41', '150', '136', '181', '41', '100', '100']],
6: [['75', '50', '87', '28', '75', '6', '50', '6', '37', '28', '49', '50']]}
```

How to get the correct output for the second part?

Thank S!

Comment: What is `shapes_dict` good for? It is passed to `read_coordinates()` but not used within. Anyway, `read_coordinates()` is never called.

Comment: I've edited the code. So sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting your keys to be for the second dictionary? Your example output showed the same keys as your color dictionary. I'm guessing you actually want the line number (assuming starting at '1') to be the key?

Also, why would you do you want your values to be list of lists rather than just a list of the provided numbers?

Comment: As pointed out in another comment `shape_dict` isn't used anywhere in your `read_coordinates` function even though you pass it. It's still unclear what you are trying to achieve. Also, you are passing `filename` to the function but still hard code the filename/path within the function (`open('file.txt', 'r')`). Use the variable that you pass.

Comment: Maybe you could explain in words what you are trying to do versus having us try to interpret your incomplete code.